# Light Fixture, Fan and GFCI share supply, all function except Light Fixture -- unless power is consumed via GFCI

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, gfci, junction-box

I have concerning behavior from a light switch and GFCI outlet. I apologize for the length, I'm trying to be thorough as I have a pretty good understand of how wiring *should* work, but it's...not...So I'm missing something somewhere.

### Setup

The junction of concern is supplied on the ***load*** side of an upstream GFCI[A] Outlet.
The junction box has a GFCI[B] Outlet, Light Fixture and Bathroom Fan all pigtailed together from GFCI[A] ***load*** (i.e. GFCI[B] supply). I feel confident the issue is in this junction box, but don't let me convince you of anything yet.

`Breaker -> GFCI[A] ==Load==> Junction Box [ GFCI[B] | Light Switch ==> Light Fixture | 3 Speed Bathroom Fan (no light) ]`

There is no connection to ground; this is old home with two wire install on this circuit. The Light Fixture, Light Switch, and GFCI[B] are new work with Romex, and are all connected together via ground for posterity, but there is no connection to ground upstream at GFCI[A].

### Behavior

In short, the light fixture will only turn on under two conditions

1. GFCI[B] outlet is removed (wires still attached to pigtail).
2. Power is consumed by some appliance via the GFCI[A] or GFCI[B] (with light switch in on position, of course)

By point 2. I mean I have an electric kettle with a switch on it at GFCI[B] and Toaster on GFCI[A]. With either plugged in and I flip power to the kettle/toaster, the light fixture comes on with it (if light switch is on, duh). The light fixture will remain on until I flip the light fixture switch to off.

Once the Light Fixture is on, it will remain on regardless of GFCI[A/B]

The Bathroom Fan functions at all times and GFCI[A/B] function at all times.

### Setup in Light Switch

Single pole switch, with black wire power-in going to top terminal, and black wire power-out at bottom terminal.

Two white wires wire nutted together. Inspected for solid contact.

Ground wires wire nutted together, and pig-tail bonded to metal box. No ground upstream, just good habits.

### Setup in GFCI[B] Junction Box

Remember this is all ***load*** side of GFCI[A]

Black wire (from load GFCI[A]) is wire-nutted to 3 other black wires. They connect to:

1. GFCI[B] LINE/SUPPLY terminal
2. Bathroom Fan
3. Light Switch ==> Light Fixture

4 White wires all are bonded via "IDEAL In Sure" wire connector (didn't have Wago's at my store). White wire from GFCI[B] is on LINE/SUPPLY terminal.

### Results of testing and investigation

1. Black to White across GFCI[B] terminals reads 119v (in essence black pigtail to white pigtail reads 119v)
2. Black to Black across light switch open reads 119v (0v when closed) regardless if GFCI[B] is connected or not.
3. Plug-in outlet tester shows "Open Ground" on GFCI[B] and no other codes.
4. Disconnecting white/black wires from GFCI[B] allows Light Fixture to operate as expected.
5. Tripping GFCI[B] "test" does not allow Light Fixture to operate. (was trying to mimic it being disconnected)
6. Tripping GFCI[A] "test" removes power from everything downstream, as expected.
7. Bathroom Fan works at all times.
8. Testing Black/White to Ground reads ~60-80v, but since this is not actually connected to Ground I believe this is meaningless.
9. With GFCI[B] connected, and electric kettle pulling power from it, the Light Fixture will turn on. Turn off the electric kettle and Light Fixture remains on, it very slightly brightens.
10. If I flip the Light Switch to on (with GCI[B] installed), the light remains off until I remove either of Black or White wire connected to GFCI[B]. Honest to god just leaving the screw loose, and then wiggling the wire until it looses contact with the outlet, then the light pops on (and stays on).
11. I originally thought this was a loose wire and maybe using the electric kettle caused a neutral to heat up, bend/expand, and then provide sufficient contact for the light to work. I've double triple double checked that wires are snug, and in contact.
12. Breaker is functioning: trips during a short.
13. Pulling power from the upstream GFCI[A] (toaster oven) will turn on the light, same as GFCI[B]
14. Pulling power from Bathroom Fan will **not** turn on the light
15. Best for last: With GFCI[B] installed (and light won't turn on) No-Contact Voltage tester reads no voltage with Light Switch **off**. With Light Switch **on**, the tester beeps indicating voltage is in there. So *something* gets through

### My thoughts

Absolutely stumped.

The only thing left I can think to try is a new GFCI outlet, or just a regular outlet. A regular outlet should suffice since it is on the load of GFCI[A]. But I am not confident this solves whatever issue is going on. Perhaps GFCI[B] is faulty and has a small short? Enough to cause a voltage drop to make the light not turn on and the no-contact beep, but enough for the bathroom fan to operate. I read 119v across the light switch in this setup, however.

Nothing can be leaking through ground since there isn't ground.

To me the absolute strangest part is that removing GFCI[B] makes the light work. Or that the Bathroom Fan *does* work while it's connected.

I have no other ideas. Thank you for your time.

Edit: The light is working now, and I'm noticing it works more often during daytime than night time. It really suggests to me it's temperature dependent (winter here) and a loose wire, perhaps at A

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. Show us the wiring from at least 2 different angles in all the boxes involve din this setup. [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/245547/edit) your question and use the button with the "mountains" to add them in.

Comment: And regarding your measurement across the switch - you're reading 0V when it's closed and 119V when it's open, not the other way around.

Comment: My first rule is that when chasing a problem of "A"... if there is a nearby "B" that is a code violation, unsafe, wrong, poor practice or stupid, fix B first.  Not least, there is no reason to do all the extra thinking required to account for *2* problems.  Here, the stupidity is ["Yo Dawg" GFCI wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/155396/two-gfcis-in-series-which-would-trip).

Comment: TLDR, to tell the truth if you have to have a plug in use for another device to do anything it is wired in series, it should be wired in parallel but in a chain with a switch interrupting the light.

Comment: Hey @brhans, regarding reading 0V when closed, I had my terminology backwards, so you're correct. I'll edit that.